# How to publish custom react component folder to npm which has all the components?

Tags: reactjs

i have a Components folder which has common folder, in that folder i have my custom components.

how can i publish all?
    common:
      grid.jsx
      dropdown.jsx
      etc...

Comment: Components:
     common:
          grid.jsx

Comment: Publishing a library is not beginner friendly ! You can look at this repo for details: https://github.com/jaebradley/example-rollup-react-component-npm-package.

Comment: This tool can be helpful for beginners.
https://bit.dev/